# Angular JS/Ionic - how to connect 2 pages together AND step through a JSON array

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a beginner with JSON and Angular. I have 4 tabs in my app. When I click on an animal category, I want a list of the animals to show up. My problem is when I click on a category, it takes me right to a particular animal's page (data is blank, don't know why).

Here is the services file which includes the JSON:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Animals', function() {

var animals =[{
        "category": "African Wildlife",
        "names": [
            {"Name": "Elephant", "Genus": "Loxodonta", "Group": "herd", "Life": "70 years", "Picture": "elephant"},
            {"Name": "Giraffe", "Genus": "Giraffa", "Group": "tower", "Life": "25 years", "Picture": "giraffe"},
            {"Name": "Hippopotamus", "Genus": "Hippopotamus", "Group": "School", "Life": "40 years", "Picture": "hippo"},
            {"Name": "Lion", "Genus": "Panthera", "Group": "pride", "Life": "15 years", "Picture": "lion"},
            {"Name": "Rhinoceros", "Genus": "Diceros", "Group": "crash", "Life": "40 years", "Picture": "rhino"},
            {"Name": "Zebra", "Genus": "Equus", "Group": "herd", "Life": "25 years", "Picture": "zebra"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Birds",
        "names": [
            {"Name": "Flamingo", "Genus": "Phoenicopterus", "Group": "colony", "Life": "25 years", "Picture": "flamingo"}, 
            {"Name": "Hummingbird", "Genus": "Damophila", "Group": "charm", "Life": "7 years", "Picture": "hummingbird"}, 
            {"Name": "Parrot", "Genus": "Trichoglossus", "Group": "pandemonium", "Life": "80 years", "Picture": "parrot"}, 
            {"Name": "Pelican", "Genus": "Pelecanus", "Group": "pod", "Life": "18 years", "Picture": "pelican"}, 
            {"Name": "Toucan", "Genus": "Ramphastos", "Group": "flock", "Life": "20 years", "Picture": "toucan"},
            {"Name": "Swan", "Genus": "Cygnus", "Group": "herd", "Life": "10 years", "Picture": "swan"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Insects",
        "names": [
            {"Name": "Ant", "Genus": "Solenopsis", "Group": "colony", "Life": "7 weeks", "Picture": "ant"},
            {"Name": "Bumblebee", "Genus": "Bombus", "Group": "swarm", "Life": "A few months", "Picture": "bee"},
            {"Name": "Butterfly", "Genus": "Curetis", "Group": "flutter", "Life": "6-8 months", "Picture": "butterfly"},
            {"Name": "Cicada", "Genus": "Cicada", "Group": "cloud", "Life": "Up to 17 years", "Picture": "cicada"},
            {"Name": "Dragonfly", "Genus": "Macromia", "Group": "N/A", "Life": "About 6 months", "Picture": "dragonfly"},
            {"Name": "Grasshopper", "Genus": "Atractomorpha", "Group": "N/A", "Life": "About 6-12 months (depends on weather)", "Picture": "grasshopper"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Reptiles",
        "names": [
            {"Name": "Alligator", "Genus": "Alligator", "Group": "congregation", "Life": "35-50 years", "Picture": "alligator"},
            {"Name": "Chameleon", "Genus": "Furcifer", "Group": "N/A", "Life": "5-8 years", "Picture": "chameleon"},
            {"Name": "Komodo Dragon", "Genus": "Varanus", "Group": "N/A", "Life": "30 years", "Picture": "komodo"},
            {"Name": "Iguana", "Genus": "Iguana", "Group": "N/A", "Life": "20 years", "Picture": "iguana"},
            {"Name": "Python", "Genus": "Apodora", "Group": "den", "Life": "20-30 years", "Picture": "python"},
            {"Name": "Snapping Turtle", "Genus": "Chelydra", "Group": "bale", "Life": "Unknown", "Picture": "turtle"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Marine",
        "names": [
            {"Name": "Dolphin", "Genus": "delphinus", "Group": "pod", "Life": "20 years", "Picture": "dolphin"},
            {"Name": "Stingray", "Genus": "dasyatis", "Group": "fever", "Life": "15 years", "Picture": "stingray"},
            {"Name": "Octopus", "Genus": "octopus", "Group": "octopuses", "Life": "2 years", "Picture": "octopus"},
            {"Name": "Sea lion", "Genus": "eumetopias", "Group": "colony", "Life": "14 years", "Picture": "sealion"},
            {"Name": "Manatee", "Genus": "trichechidae", "Group": "herd", "Life": "40 years", "Picture": "manatee"},
            {"Name": "Horned Starfish", "Genus": "protoreaster", "Group": "tird", "Life": "35 years", "Picture": "starfish"},
            {"Name": "Killer Whale", "Genus": "orcinus", "Group": "pod", "Life": "67 years", "Picture": "orca"},
            {"Name": "Sea turtle", "Genus": "chelonia", "Group": "bale", "Life": "53 years", "Picture": "seaturtle"},
            {"Name": "Crab", "Genus": "brachyura", "Group": "cast", "Life": "24 years", "Picture": "crab"},
            {"Name": "Seahorse", "Genus": "hippocampus", "Group": "shoal", "Life": "4 years", "Picture": "seahorse"}
        ]
    }
];

return {
all: function() {
  return animals;
},
remove: function(animal) {
  animals.splice(animals.indexOf(animal), 1);
},
get: function(animalId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    if (animals[i].Name === animalId) {
      return animals[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
};
});
```

Here is the controllers.js file:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, Animals) {

$scope.animals = Animals.all();
})

.controller('AnimalsCtrl', function($scope, Animals) {
// With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
// when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
// To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
// listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
//
//$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
//});

$scope.animals = Animals.all();
$scope.remove = function(animal) {
 Animals.remove(animal);
};
})

.controller('AnimalDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Animals) {
$scope.animal = Animals.get($stateParams.animalId);
})

.controller('AnimalsCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.animal = Animals.get($stateParams.animalId);
});
```

Here is the app.js file:

```
angular.module('starter' ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

}
if (window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
});
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
.state('tab', {
url: '/tab',
abstract: true,
templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})

.state('tab.dash', {
url: '/dash',
views: {
  'tab-dash': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
    controller: 'DashCtrl'
  }
}
})

.state('tab.animals', {
  url: '/animals',
  views: {
    'tab-animals': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-animals.html',
      controller: 'AnimalsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.animal-detail', {
  url: '/animals/:animalId',
  views: {
    'tab-animals': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/animal-detail.html',
      controller: 'AnimalDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('tab.location', {
url: '/location',
views: {
  'tab-location': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-location.html',
    controller: 'LocationCtrl'
  }
}
})

.state('tab.zoos',{
  url: '/zoos',
  views: {
      'tab-zoos': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-zoos.html',
          controller: 'ZoosCtrl'
      }
  }
});

// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

})
```

Here is my home page, the picture doesn't show up for some reason:

```
<ion-view view-title="Welcome">
<ion-content class="padding">
<h2>Welcome to the Animal Facts Generator</h2>
<p>
    To begin, select a group below.
</p>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in animals" href="#/tab/animals/{{item.category}}">
        <img ng-src="img/{{item.category.names[0].Picture}}.png">
        <h2>{{item.category}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is the page I am supposed to go to but it doesn't go here:

```
<ion-view view-title="Animals">
<ion-content>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="a in animals" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/animals/{{a.category.names[a].Name}}">
    <img ng-src="../img/{{a.category.names[a].Picture}}.png">
    <h2>{{a.category.names[a].Name}}</h2>
    <p>{{a.category.names[a].Genus}}</p>
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I am not sure how to access the name of each animal.

I have to be referencing something wrong but I don't know what.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show? The list of all categories or list of names withing single category?

Comment: I'm trying to show the names of the animals in the category when the specific category is clicked

Comment: Create fiddle/plnkr.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your animals data, your service code has logic error

```
get: function(animalId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        if (animals[i].Name === animalId) {  //<---HERE SHOULD USE animals[i].category NOT Name
            return animals[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Your AnimalDetailCtrl also has the same problem. Should give Array for ng-repeat.

```
.controller('AnimalDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Animals) {
    $scope.animal = Animals.get($stateParams.animalId); //<---USE console.log AND CHECK YOUR DATA
})
```

In animal-detail.html, the names that you want to display should follow $scope.animal data structure.

```
<h2>{{a.category.names[a].Name}}</h2>
<p>{{a.category.names[a].Genus}}</p>
```

At least, the spelling error need to check again. For example, you call `$scope.animal` in `AnimalDetailCtrl`, but using `ng-repeat="a in animals"` on the template.